# Transferring Skype calls with Skype4Com - is it possible?

Tags: c#, forwarding, skype4com

I am currently working on a skype plugin / application in c# which I would like to be able to transfer / forward calls to another skype address.

I tried to use `ICall.Transfer();`, which (as i found out later) basically only transfers files instead of calls.
Then I tried to use `ICall.Forward();`, but that function tries to send the calls to voicemail and does not allow me to set any other target to forward the call to.

So my question is: Is it possible to transfer / forward a call using basic Skype4Com functions, or should I try to write a workaround involving creating a conference call and then leaving the call, so the 'forwarded' caller is left in the conversation?

I would really like some insight on this.

**EDIT:**

I solved it. As it turns out the `ICall.Transfer();` function was the way to go.
I just overlooked a simple error I made, which could have been prevented with some simple debugging.

using the following:

```
ICall.Transfer("skype.address");
```

works, but I was trying to load the skype address dynamically, which had an error somewhere in the process.